# Getting started with complex projection in nHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I am looking at nHibernate and Entity Framework as possible ORMs to introduce into a system. I am trying to perform the equivalent to the following SQL using nHibernate:

```
SELECT
   a.Id,
   a.Name,
   a.Etc,
   MAX(CASE WHEN (c.dId IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As IsLinked
FROM
   tA a
   INNER JOIN tAB ab ON a.Id = ab.aId
   INNER JOIN tB b ON ab.bId = b.Id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN tC c ON b.cId = c.Id
   AND c.dId = 'x'
WHERE
   a.Id = 'y'
GROUP BY
   a.Id,
   a.Name,
   a.Etc,
```

Basically I want to select from table tA and also check whether the entry in tA is linked or not to data in table tC. The linkage between the two tables is complex:

- tA has a many to many relationship to tB (using table tAB)
- tB has a one to many relationship with the table tC using the Foreign Key tB.cId
- tC has a Foreign Key tc.dId to another table tD

Using the Entity Framework Code First I can't use Include as it does not allow filtering but I can use projection so I get a functionally correct query using:

```
var query = from a in db.As
            where a.Id == 'y'
            select new
            {
               a,
               IsLinked = a.Bs
                           .Select(b => b.Cs)
                           .Select(c => c.Where(n => n.dId == 'x'))
                           .Select(h => h.Count()).Max() > 0
             };
```

The SQL generated is complex and slow, but works. I'm struggling to achieve the same functionality in nHibernate starting from a QueryOver:

```
var query = session.QueryOver<A>().Where(a => a.Id == 'y');
```

How do I create an equivalent projection that works across the multiple / nested join types (one being an OUTER join) without resorting to HQL? Or am I best off (since performance is likely to be poor) either:

- Making two queries (one that retrieves the data and one that establishes the linkage)
- Introducing views that encapsulate the complexity of the joins

Thanks

Comment: do you get an error when substituding `db.As` with `session.Query<A>()` (`using NHibernate.Linq;`)

Comment: Good suggestion... it compiles but at runtime I get a NoViableAltException thrown which appear to be caused by the `.Select(h => h.Count()).Max() > 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this query should be equivalent, can you try it?

```
var query = from a in db.As
        where a.Id == 'y'
        select new
        {
           a,
           IsLinked = a.Bs.SelectMany(b => b.Cs).Any(c => c.dId == 'x')
           // or
           IsLinked = a.Bs.Any(b => b.Cs.Any(c => c.dId == 'x'))
         };
```

Comment: Both approaches compile, but the first option results in a NotSupportedException in the VisitAdditionalFromClause method when executed. The second works and the resultant SQL is only slightly less performant than the hand written SQL. Thank you.

Comment: As a point of interest, both approaches work with Entity Framework though the former produces more compact code. However, the SQL is less efficient than that produced by nHibernate as the "Any" is translated into both a check if something exists and a check if something doesn't exist!!! In other words EF creates a CASE and says `WHEN EXISTS (...) THEN 1 WHEN NOT EXISTS (...) THEN 0` (i.e. runs the sub select twice. Whereas nHibernate creates a CASE and says `WHEN EXISTS (...) THEN 1 ELSE 0` which is obviously going to be more efficient!

Comment: Just to be fair to Entity Framework, having ANY execute EXISTS and NOT EXISTS is a known [bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/695744/entity-framework-generates-inefficient-sql-for-any) and the suggested workaround of using `.Count(c => c.dId == 'x') > 0` produces SQL that performs significantly better than the nHibernate's SQL (in fact it is as performant as my hand writen SQL). Perhaps if I could get the first approach working in nHibernate it would also produce more efficient SQL.

Comment: Correction: using `.Count(c => c.dId == 'x')` in the projection is efficient, but adding `> 0` in the projection hits a similar [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/708457/entity-framework-generates-inefficient-sql-when-using-boolean-operators-in-projections) in Entity Framework.  Therefore you need to avoid the greater than within the projection and perform the test within your client code.